# DensityPlot with 4 region. Help please!

Tags: plotting, functions, color, regions

How to write a function in Wolfram Mathematica that returns the values 0,1,2,3 in random order and draw a diagram for it as shown in the picture using the DensityPlot function. Help please!![image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Try: `RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 20]` and use it in your post if required. I don't understand how this sequence will result in this density plot, so please elaborate.

Comment: Okey, Thank you!